# How to bind secondary x-axis to the first in plotly?

Tags: plotly, axis

Let's say I have a figure with a secondary x-axis, like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCoLC.png)
What I want to achieve is that the secondary x-axis is a function of the first one. (Here C to F)
One way to do it is by setting the ranges of the axes, so that they line up, but this way if I move the x-axis around, the secondary x-axis stays still. The other way would be, that I plot the data for both of the x-axis, but I'm not sure if it's possible.
Does anyone have a fair solution?

Here is the code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.graph_objs.layout import YAxis,XAxis,Margin

layout = go.Layout(
    title="Double X Axis Example",
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title="Celcius"
    ),
    xaxis2 = XAxis(
        title="Fahrenheits",
        overlaying= 'x', 
        side= 'top',
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="Y values"
    ),
)

# Create figure with secondary x-axis
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[10, 20, 30], y=[4.5, 6, 5], name="data set in celcius"),
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[40, 60, 80], y=[4, 5, 6.5], name="data set in fahrenheit", xaxis='x2'),
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: I do not understand what you have realized. For example, if I update the code for the second graph with the following content, the lines will be horizontal. `fig.add_trace(    go.Scatter(x=[40, 60, 80], y=[4, 5, 6.5], name="data set in fahrenheit", xaxis='x'),)` You may be able to get an answer if you have the expected output, even if it is handwritten.